# Springboot 3.2 and Java 17 Compiler Error: "Attribute must be constant" in custom annotation interface with dynamic default message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-17

I'm encountering a compiler error in my custom annotation interface (ValidPageSize) on line 18, where I have a dynamic default message using the Translator.toLocale method. The error message states "Attribute must be constant." I understand that annotation attributes must be compile-time constants, but I need to provide a dynamic default message.

```
// Custom annotation interface with dynamic default message causing compiler error

@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = PageSizeValidator.class)
public @interface ValidPageSize {

    // Compiler error occurs on the following line (line 18)
    String message() default Translator.toLocale("validation.pageSize.invalid.default"); //line 18

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Is there a workaround or best practice to address this issue and have a dynamic default message for the message attribute in a custom annotation? Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

tried creating Enum with value as `Translator.toLocale("validation.pageSize.invalid.default")` that didnt work either

Comment: @StephenC this is an annotation, it doesn't work like an interface (even though it looks like one). You can't define method bodies, and default values must be constants (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2):

Any value in an annotation must be a compile-time constant. That means primitive literals, String literals (including Strings created by concatenating other literals), `Class` objects and enum constants. This limitation holds not just when you fill in the annotation values when you use the annotation, but also the default values.

There is some good news for you though - the Bean Validation framework supports translatable messages by itself. The official documentation can be found at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-message-interpolation, but it's actually very simple:

- Create a file called `ValidationMessages.properties` as a root resource (with Maven, put it directly in `src/main/resources`). Add a key-entry pair for the default translation. For example:

  ```
  validation.pageSize.invalid.default = The page size is invalid
  ```
- Add files for other locales. This works like `ResourceBundle`, e.g. `ValidationMessages_fr.properties`.
- In your annotation, use `{validation.pageSize.invalid.default}`. The curly braces let the Bean validation framework interpolate the message.

If this is still not sufficient, you can define a custom `MessageInterpolator` as specified in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-custom-message-interpolation.